# Safari на ipad и PC не видит слайдер и кнопки

Tags: html, css

Почему сафари не видит кнопки и слайдер на сайте http://one-love.by ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<button class="btn-orange" type="submit" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add">Купить</button>

.product-item .item .data-footer .btn-orange {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
.btn-orange {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #faa912;
    padding: 0 20px 0 45px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: transparent url(../img/cartb.png) no-repeat 20px 50%;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

слайдер

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-text">
        <h2>Новая коллекция 2018 года</h2>
        <p>Мы подготовили для Вас новую коллекцию одежды весна-лето 2018 года. В нашем ассортименте появились новые аксессуары и женская одежда, которая порадует Вас!</p>
        <a href="" class="btn-white">Перейти в каталог</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-img">

    </div>
</div>

header .slider-box .slider-bg .item {
    height: 405px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
header .slider-box .slider-bg .item .item-text {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 6% 0;
}
header .slider-box .slider-bg .item .item-text h2 {
    font-family: 'PlayfairDisplay';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
header .slider-box .slider-bg .item .item-text p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
}
header .slider-box .slider-bg .item .item-img {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    background: url(../img/sliderimg.png) no-repeat 50% bottom;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: А какие кнопки не видит PC?

Comment: добавить в корзину слайд в целом

Comment: Странно, но я вижу кнопки "Купить",  "Перейти в каталог", изображение девушки с надписью Fashion. Проверил в IE, Chrome, огнелисе

Comment: я в safari не вижу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

header .slider-box .slider-bg .item - здесь используется flex. Для safari свои особенности

https://habrahabr.ru/post/330410/